# Div's misalign after child <p> inserted

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div's, one 50% width, the other 25%.

They're suppose to both sit centred horizontally on the one line.

I can get this working fine. But when I insert a paragraph they break.

Any idea why?

http://jsfiddle.net/3KuJa/

html:

```
<section>
    <div class="twothird"> </div>
    <div class="onethird"><p>test</p></div>
</section>
```

css:

```
.onethird {
    width: 25%;
    background: white;
    min-height: 20em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20em 3%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2em;
    text-align:left;
}

.twothird {
    width: 50%;
    background: white;
    min-height: 20em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20em 3%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2em;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: he funny :-) I would use floats or display:inline-block

Comment: both `div` should be in same line vertically or horizontally?

Comment: @chrisツ : OP is already using that!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor OOOPs, sry

Comment: Inline block item default to alignment `baseline` try `vertical-align:top` Oh..and don't forget to account for whitespace.

Comment: `vertical-align:top` did the trick

Comment: @RyanKing Excellent. I added an answer so you can mark it as correct if you would be so kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline block elements align, by default to `baseline`

This should fix it if applied to both inline-block divs

CSS

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

**Adjusted [JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3KuJa/5/)**

You may have to widen the display window to check.

Answer (score 2):

since you have `box-shadow`, i am proposing a solution supported by IE8+ :

use `display :table /table-cell` for `section` and `div`

```
section {
    display:table; /* make parent table type */
    width:60%; /* give width */
    margin :0 auto; /* center your section */
    border:1px solid green /* just for display */
}


.onethird {
    width: 25%;
    background: white;
    min-height: 20em;
    display:table-cell;
    /* display: inline-block; changed this value */
    margin: 20em 3%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2em;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.twothird {
    width: 50%;
    border:1px solid red;
    background: white;
    min-height: 20em;
    display:table-cell;
    /* display: inline-block;  changed this value */
    margin: 20em 3%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2em;
    text-align:left;
}
```

**Keep in mind :** your fiddle doesn't have set `width` and `height` to `html, body`...always declare that, it avoids many messy problems later in DOM - *rule of thumb* :)

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3KuJa/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is indeed the interaction of the baseline alignment between the `p` and the empty inline box to the left of it.

In addition to using `vertical-align: top` to fix the problem, you can also use `overflow:auto` applied to `.onethird` and `.twothird`, which triggers a new block formatting context which prevents the text lines from the two inline-block containers from interacting with each other.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/6vnh3/